# Cannot encrypt password in WSO2 Identity Server 5.9.0 (wso2is)

Tags: encryption, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I added the `secrets` to the end of the deployment.toml file and executed ciphertool. But it returns an error as;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.ciphertool.utils.Utils.resolveKeyStorePath(Utils.java:347)
    at org.wso2.ciphertool.utils.Utils.setSystemProperties(Utils.java:256)
    at org.wso2.ciphertool.CipherTool.initialize(CipherTool.java:127)
    at org.wso2.ciphertool.CipherTool.main(CipherTool.java:60)
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is already reported via https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/6939.

It is already fixed in the latest cipher tool component. IS5.10.0-GA pack includes this fix

Comment: This is happening for latest wso2am WUM updated pack also. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the accepted answer, this is fixed in a later version. The jar with fix can be found [here](https://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/org/wso2/ciphertool/org.wso2.ciphertool/1.1.9)(org.wso2.ciphertool-1.1.9.jar).

You can remove the cipher-tool jar inside `<HOME>/lib` and add the cipher-tool 1.1.9 jar from above.

Comment: This is happening for latest wso2am WUM updated pack also. How to fix it?